# How to write test result(pass/fail) in excel sheet using selenium web driver and java without hard coding row_num and Col_num in my program

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

**Below is my program to write the data in Excel sheet:-**

```
public static void write_test_result(String result, String sheet_name, String filePath,int row_num,int col_num) throws EncryptedDocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheet_name);
        sh.getRow(row_num).createCell(col_num).setCellValue(result);
        //sh.createRow(row_num).createCell(col_num).setCellValue(result);
        wb.write(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
    }
```

**Calling this method in my program like this:**

```
FileIOLibrary.write_test_result("Pass",sheet_name,FilePath, 7,5);
```

Here row_num=7 and Col_num=5 i am hardcoding everytime, but i dont want to hard code these values.

How can I loop over the call of the `write_test_result` method and increase the `row_num`/`Col_num` each iteration?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you are asking in the end. Are you trying to loop over the call of your `write_test_result` method and increase the `row_num`/`Col_num` each iteration?

Comment: yes correct , can you help me out how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based off of your comment stating that you wish to iterate over the `write_test_result` method and increase the row/column index each time, here is the needed loop structure:

```
int maxRowCount = 10; // set this to the total number of rows to iterate over
int maxColumnCount = 15; // set this to the total number of columns to iterate over

for (int rowCount = 1; rowCount < maxRowCount; rowCount++) {
    for (int columnCount = 1; columnCount < maxColumnCount; columnCount++) {
        FileIOLibrary.write_test_result("Pass", sheet_name, FilePath, rowCount, columnCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your response, I will use in my Framework and i will let you know the result.